# How to figure out which SDK/APIs a closed-source iOS/Android app uses

Tags: android, ios

I’m considering writing a research paper on the effects of first-party APIs on the types of apps that get developed. While I could certainly pick an app and check to see if it mentions using an API in the marketing (or pester the devs via email), that’s time consuming and error prone.

It would be easier if there was a way to analyze an app binary to see if it uses, for example, ARKit/ARCore. Is there a tool for doing something like that?

Comment: On Android, you can just open the APK in JADx and see if there are packages that don't match the app.

Comment: What do you mean by “don’t match”?

Comment: Well if the app is made my Facebook, for example, Facebook's stuff will be under the `com.facebook` package. However, the app might be using Jared Rummler's ColorPickerPreference somewhere, which would show under `com.jaredrummler`.

Comment: Yeah, but that won’t be the case for packages that are part of the OS, right?

Comment: No, but if the app is using the Samsung SDK or something, you'll know when it crashes on any other device.